# How to resize an image in python, while retaining aspect ratio, given a target size?

Tags: python, opencv, math

First off part of me feels like this is a stupid question, sorry about that. Currently the most accurate way I've found of calculating the optimum scaling factor (best width and height for target pixel count while retaining aspect ratio) is iterating through and choosing the best one however there must be a better way of doing this.

An example:

```
import cv2, numpy as np
img = cv2.imread("arnold.jpg")

img.shape[1] # e.g. width  = 700
img.shape[0] # e.g. height = 979

# e.g. Total  pixels : 685,300

TARGET_PIXELS = 100000
MAX_FACTOR    = 0.9
STEP_FACTOR   = 0.001
iter_factor   = STEP_FACTOR
results       = dict()

while iter_factor < MAX_RATIO:
     img2 = cv2.resize(img, (0,0), fx=iter_factor, fy=iter_factor)
     results[img2.shape[0]*img2.shape[1]] = iter_factor
     iter_factor += step_factor

best_pixels = min(results, key=lambda x:abs(x-TARGET_PIXELS))
best_ratio  = results[best_pixels]

print best_pixels # e.g. 99750
print best_ratio  # e.g. 0.208
```

I know there are probably some errors lying around in the code above i.e. there is no check in the results dictionary for an existing key but I am more concerned with a different approach which I cannot figure out was looking into lagrangian optimisation but that seems quite complex also for a simple problem. Any ideas?

** EDIT AFTER ANSWER **

Going to provide the code if anyone is interested in the answer

```
import math, cv2, numpy as np

# load up an image
img = cv2.imread("arnold.jpg")

TARGET_PIXEL_AREA = 100000.0

ratio = float(img.shape[1]) / float(img.shape[0])
new_h = int(math.sqrt(TARGET_PIXEL_AREA / ratio) + 0.5)
new_w = int((new_h * ratio) + 0.5)

img2 = cv2.resize(img, (new_w,new_h))
```

Comment: Hmm this code does not maintain aspect ratio for me... If I provide a wide image for instance, it stretches it vertically to fill a square the size of the TARGET_PIXEL_AREA

Comment: I think you need to test for portrait or landscape (from the aspect ratio) and use one of two formulae computing width from height or height from width depending upon ratio larger or smaller than 1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is my approach,

```
aspectRatio = currentWidth / currentHeight
heigth * width = area
```

So,

```
height * (height * aspectRatio) = area
height² = area / aspectRatio
height = sqrt(area / aspectRatio)
```

At that point we know the target height, and `width = height * aspectRatio`.

Ex:

```
area = 100 000
height = sqrt(100 000 / (700/979)) = 373.974
width = 373.974 * (700/979) = 267.397
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah this is what I was looking for silly me seems so simple now!

Answer (score 1):

I think the fastest and cleaner way is:

```
from PIL import Image
from math import sqrt

img=Image.open(PATH)
img.thumbnails([round(sqrt(TARGET_PIXEL_AREA))]*2)
```

I hope it will help