# How can i resize images given a certain ratio?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, opencv, image-processing

I have many images of different sizes in my directory, however i want to resize them all by a certain ratio, let's say 0.25 or 0.2, it should be a variable i can control from my code and i want the resulting images to be an output in another directory.

I looked into this approach supplied by this previous question [How to resize an image in python, while retaining aspect ratio, given a target size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33701929/how-to-resize-an-image-in-python-while-retaining-aspect-ratio-given-a-target-s)

> ```
> Here is my approach,
>
> aspectRatio = currentWidth / currentHeight
> heigth * width = area
> So,
>
> height * (height * aspectRatio) = area
> height² = area / aspectRatio
> height = sqrt(area / aspectRatio)
> At that point we know the target height, and width = height * aspectRatio.
>
> Ex:
>
> area = 100 000
> height = sqrt(100 000 / (700/979)) = 373.974
> width = 373.974 * (700/979) = 267.397
> ```

but it lacks lots of details for example:how to transform these sizes back on the image which libraries to use and so on..

**Edit:** looking more into the docs **img.resize** looks ideal (although i also noticed .thumbnail) but i can't find a proper example on a case like mine.

Comment: If you look at the question, the person used opencv (`cv2`) with method [`cv2.resize`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize). E.g. `img2 = cv2.resize(img, (new_w, new_h))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own small routine to resize and resave pictures:

```
import cv2

def resize(oldPath,newPath,factor): 
    """Resize image on 'oldPath' in both dimensions by the same 'factor'. 
    Store as 'newPath'."""
    def r(image,f):
        """Resize 'image' by 'f' in both dimensions."""
        newDim = (int(f*image.shape[0]),int(f*image.shape[1]))
        return cv2.resize(image, newDim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

    cv2.imwrite(newPath, r(cv2.imread(oldPath), factor))
```

And test it like so:

```
# load and resize (local) pic, save as new file (adapt paths to your system)
resize(r'C:\Pictures\2015-08-05 10.58.36.jpg',r'C:\Pictures\mod.jpg',0.4)
# show openened modified image
cv2.imshow("...",cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\partner\Pictures\mod.jpg'))
# wait for keypress for diplay to close
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

You should add some error handling, f.e.:

- no image at given path
- image not readable (file path permissions)
- image not writeable (file path permissions)

Comment: In the time that took to answer it i was able to write my solution but i'll accept the answer thanks to the effort put into it. However the outcome pic is blurry, is that normal and can it be fixed? kindly refer to my answer bellow

Answer (score 3):

```
from PIL import Image


ratio = 0.2
img = Image.open('/home/user/Desktop/test_pic/1-0.png')
hsize = int((float(img.size[1])*float(ratio)))
wsize = int((float(img.size[0])*float(ratio)))
img = img.resize((wsize,hsize), Image.ANTIALIAS)
img.save('/home/user/Desktop/test_pic/change.png')
```

Comment: You choose PIL - the `Image.ANTIALIAS` is a parameter to `resize` that "causes" the blurryness. See [PIL.Image.Image.resize](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize)  and the options you can give it. Use `PIL.Image.BICUBIC` or  `PIL.Image.LANCZOS` instead.

Comment: Can you edit my answer to what would be ideal as i find it a bit simpler than yours than post it as your answer and have me acept, thanks in advance.

Comment: No, experiment yourself ;) you can select your own answer as solution after 48h.

Comment: Too late:).Thanks again